# Gitlab pipeline does not properly package javafx application

Tags: java, maven, javafx, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a problem with my pipeline in GitLab. I'm trying to compile and build an artifact of multimodule javafx application. In IntelliJ I'm using maven to clean and package the program with "mvn clean package" command and output jar in target is working properly but while executing instruction below in gitlab pipeline artefact gives this error.

> sty 31, 2024 12:24:23 PM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup  WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @55249a40'                          Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw                                                                    Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found          at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:283)                                      at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:253)                                               at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:263)                                                               at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:290)                                               at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)                                               at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:651)                                          at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:671)                                    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)                            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)                                                              Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found                           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:95)                             at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)                             ... 1 more                                                                                                      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found                                                         at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:275)                                                               at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:290)                                               at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)                                               at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:651)                                          at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:671)                                    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)                            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)

I'm using this syntax for my pipeline

```
image: maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17 
 
cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository
stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  image: maven:latest
  script:
    - mvn clean package
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar
```

Maybe someone can help with this because none potential solutions work. I tried to clean module-info.java and export all necessary classes to fxml but it also did not work.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Info on packaging JavaFX applications is in the [packaging section of the JavaFX tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info).